# How to call angular js function controller from jquery in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How to call angularjs function or controller from jquery 
I am new to this angularjs
here is my function here i have to pass the var1 and var2 from jquery i have searched many articles but i cant understand. Please help me

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function customersController($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("https://tic.com/testingservice/HttpService.svc/operator/var1/var2")
        .success(function (response) { $scope.names = response; });
    }
```

Comment: -_- Why you need jquery ?? You have angularjs. Try to learn use it properly

Comment: If you need var1, var2 to be dynamically defined from server side script at page rendering time, you can use module.value('var1', foo) and inject var1 in your controller

Comment: Please help me how to call angularjs from jquery i want to have both these in my webapplication

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If I **speak general**, there can be cases when jQuery use is need in Angularjs app i.e. jQuery plugin is used that isn't available in Angular version.

Every Controller has $scope/this and You can access the scope of an angular element if you have an ID tag attached to the same DOM element as the ng-controller:

the DOM:

```
<div id="myctrl" ng-controller="MyCtrl"></div>
```

your controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.anyFunc = function(var1, var2) {
      // var1, var2 passed from jquery call will be available here
      //do some stuff here
   }
}
```

in jQuery you do this and it will access that controller and call that function :

```
angular.element('#myctrl').scope().anyFunc('value1','value2');
```

**Running Sample**

```js
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.anyFunc = function (var1, var2) {
        alert("I am var1 = " + var1);
        alert("I am var2 = " + var2);
    };
});

$(function(){

    $("#hit").on("click",function(){
       
          angular.element($("#myctrl")).scope().anyFunc('VAR1 VALUE', 'VAR2 VALUE');
    
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div id="myctrl" ng-app='app' ng-controller="MyCtrl">
Call via jQuery
<button id="hit">Call</button>
</div>
```

Happy Helping!

Comment: I am using it in asp.net i cant get it please help me i cant access the angularjs. Is any thing wrong with the accessing the element

Comment: oops asp.net isn't mentioned in initial question though :) i have not knowledge of asp.net, i would have been finding asp.net+angular+jquery tutorial if i were at your place

Answer (score 4):

Both the above answers helped me a lot finally i got the answers

```
$(function(){

   $("#hit").on("click",function(){

      angular.element($("#myctrl")).scope().anyFunc('VAR1 VALUE', 'VAR2 VALUE');

  });

});

function customersController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.anyFunc = function (var1, var2) {
    alert("I am var1 = " + var1);
    alert("I am var2 = " + var2);
$http.get("https://tic.com/testingservice/HttpService.svc/operator/var1/var2")
    .success(function (response) { $scope.names = response; });
};
   }



 <div id="myctrl" ng-app='' ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 Call via jQuery
 <button id="hit">Call</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try Like this

```js
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('jqueryCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.callFromJquery = function (data) {
            alert(data);
        };
    });
$(function () {
    $("#press").on("click", function () {
        angular.element($("#jquery")).scope().callFromJquery('I Called You ! Angular !');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div id="jquery" ng-app='app' ng-controller="jqueryCtrl">
Just Press ME
<button id="press">Press ME</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using it in asp.net i cant get it please help me i cant access the angularjs. Is any thing wrong with the accessing the element

Comment: Did you properly refferenced jquery and angularj ??

Comment: yes i have properly referenced angularjs and jquery. Both are working properly . But after i used the above code it is not working.